# ReSharper сбрасывает проект для отладки

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, resharper

Создаю проект cmake, используя стандартные средства msvs. Далее генерирую конфигурацию cmake используя cmake-gui, тут старался ничего не трогать, оставил всё стандартное, только генератор указал msvs. Далее открываю получившийся проект в студии уже. Собираю и запускаю по ctr f5, ловлю ошибку что он не может найти ...Debug\ALL_BUILD. А этого исполняемого файла естественно нет. По непонятной мне причине студия запускает отладку именно его а не собранного экзешника проекта. Если попытаться проект с экзешником назначить автозагружаемым проектом, как это указано в других похожих вопросах, то при нажатии ctr f5 он всё равно пытается запустить ALL_BUILD, хотя exe проекта собран и спокойно запускается, также можно руками запустить его отладку. Если отключить ReSharper то всё работает как и должно, запускается сразу собранный exe для отладки. Как бороть ReSharper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина в том, что CMake по умолчанию делает `ALL_BUILD`, запускаемым проектом. Поэтому после генерации можно нажать правой кнопкой по нужному проекту и сделать «Set as StartUp Project». После этого всё должно работать как надо. Resharper ни при чём. У меня он тоже стоит и никогда проблем не было.

Если же нужно поменять проект по умолчанию, нужно выставить свойство [VS_STARTUP_PROJECT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/VS_STARTUP_PROJECT.html) в нужный проект. Будет это выглядеть как-то так:

```
set_property(DIRECTORY PROPERTY VS_STARTUP_PROJECT ${PROJECT_NAME})
```